# MariaDB select query returns an empty response

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mariadb

I'm working on a .NET application that handles the synchronization of multiple databases. Currently, I'm working on querying data from the table mdl_user in a database on my MariaDB Server which exists on a virtual machine (will be deployed to a physical server later on).

When I do the following query in a terminal on the virtual machine (after connecting to the database) I get the following response:

```
SELECT     u.id,     u.username,     u.firstname,     u.lastname FROM     mdl_user u;
```

[image]

But when I query the database in my .NET App as follows I get an empty response:

**ViewController:**

```
    // GET: EtudiantController
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var adUsers = _activeDirectoryService.GetUsers().ToList();
        var moodleUsers = _moodleService.GetAllUsers().ToList();
        var appUsers = es.GetAll();
        Console.WriteLine(moodleUsers.Count);

        var viewModelList = appUsers.Select(appUser => new EtudiantViewModel
        {
            Etudiant = appUser,
            IsNotInActiveDirectory = !adUsers.Contains(appUser.Email),
            IsNotInMoodle = !moodleUsers.Contains(appUser.Email.Split('@')[0]),
        }).ToList();

        return View(viewModelList);
    }
```

Console.WriteLine(moodleUsers.Count); returns 0 in the Console.

Comment: Were you able to execute any database quey successfully? I think the issue is in the DbContext.

Comment: Which MariaDB version? Which connector?

Comment: @Turash I'm not using this database in the application, I'm just querying it. The database is linked to another service (moodle).

Comment: @danblack 10.11.4-MariaDB-1~deb12u1

Comment: do u have access to moodle service? What I am trying to say here is,I think _moodleSerice is returnig 0  due to connection exception. Most probably port related issue or connection string. You have to debug it there.

Comment: @Turash It turns out the issue was with the mariadb server. It wasn't well configured for remote access. It's been fixed now.